# Can we use conditions in ifdef MACROS in C or SystemVerilog?

Tags: c, macros, verilog

I want something like that

```
    `ifdef N_O > N_I
        `define GREATER 1
    `else
        `define LESSER 1
    `endif
```

But cannot do. Any solution or reading?

I tried hard to do this but could not do it.

Comment: The C preprocessor have `#if`.

Comment: C and Verilog are very different. Please focus on one language per question.

Comment: I am using Verilog and I want to use conditions in MACROS. Also, there is no ```#if``` in verilog

Comment: It would help to show us how you intend to use these macro definitions. Also how are `N_O` and `N_I` defined? Otherwise we have an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 0):

Verilog does not provide such a facility. There is only one action possible with text macros: checking for their existence. Therefore there are  `` `ifdef ``,  `` `ifndef ``, and  `` `elsif ``. All accept only a single argument which is the name of a text macro.

In many cases, however, this shortage of functionality could be augmented by using `generate` verilog features. Use of this feature is preferable because verilog controls syntax and scoping of declarations.

The following is an example of using generated functionality:

```
module mod #(parameter N_0=1, parameter N_1=2)(input logic in1, in2, output logic out);
    if (N_1 > N_2) begin
         always_comb
             out = in1;
    end
    else begin
         always_comb 
             out  = in2;
    end
endmoudle
```

This was a made up example to demonstrate the feature, which could be implemented without 'generate' blocks:

```
    alwas_comb begin
        if (N_1 > N_2) out = in1;
        else out = in2;
    end
```

However, the generate constructs cannot solve all the problem, therefore mixing of text macros and generate blocks is often needed.